# Class 'Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, google-cloud-platform, gsp, bucket

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
require __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';

$storage = new StorageClient();
```

That as my code.Here I have installed composer on windows and getting following error:-

Fatal error:  Class 'Google\Cloud\StorageClient' not found in **C:\xampp\htdocs\fingertips\application\controllers\teacher.php** on line **214**

And even after running commands with composer to use google cloud api's, then also nothing is happening.

On cmd, when I am running this, "composer require google/cloud-storage" ,I am getting this

Using version ^1.3 for google/cloud-storage
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

I have run so many commands to fix this but didnt get anything in success.Can somebody please help what went wrong

Comment: Reading the comments on other answers, it appears the original problem described in your post has been resolved. Perhaps you should edit the question to add information about the further problem, including errors you see, but omitting private information like project IDs. I'm having a bit of trouble determining where you're getting stuck now.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your second question, you didn't include the actual error you're seeing.

I can see an issue with this code block though:

```
require __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';

$storage = new StorageClient();
$file = fopen($params['book']['tmp_name'], 'r');
$bucket = $storage->bucket('fingertips-books');
$object = $bucket->upload($params['book']['name'], [
    'name' => 'test.pdf'
]);
```

I'm missing the actual data you want to upload. The upload method needs data to upload. This should work:

```
require __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';

$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket('fingertips-books');
$object = $bucket->upload(file_get_contents($params['book']['tmp_name']), [
    'name' => 'test.pdf'
]);
```

See the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/latest/storage/bucket?method=upload) for more examples of how to go about uploading a file.

Comment: <pre>Array
    (
    [chapter] => 449
    [topic] => 
    [description] => dsds
    [book] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2017-03-23.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php97AA.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 45022
        )

    
)
</pre>

Comment: This is the params variable

Comment: so the error you're getting looks like it is indeed missing the data (0 [size])
What happens if you try my adjusted method?

Comment: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message '{
 &quot;error&quot;: {
  &quot;errors&quot;: [
   {
    &quot;domain&quot;: &quot;global&quot;,
    &quot;reason&quot;: &quot;authError&quot;,
    &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Invalid Credentials&quot;,
    &quot;locationType&quot;: &quot;header&quot;,
    &quot;location&quot;: &quot;Authorization&quot;
   }
  ],
  &quot;code&quot;: 401,
  &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Invalid Credentials&quot;
 }
}

Comment: This means that you're actually missing authentication. Due to the filename you're using for the PDF, I'm guessing you're running this locally on a Windows machine.
You'll need to run a gcloud command to create the Application Default Credentials which are used to authenticate requests done locally. When the app is deployed this will be done automagically.
Perform the steps listed in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#libauth)

Comment: I strongly advise changing the comment above as it contains the service account name and this also includes the project ID. That being said, have you installed gcloud on your development machine and have you run the command "gcloud auth application-default login" afterwards? This should fix the local authentication issue...

Comment: Thnx I really appreciate @Edo Akse

Comment: Many thnx now files are getting uploaded but pdf files giving error "Failed to load the document"....Can you suggest something on it ?....may be at the time of upload I am doing something wrong

Comment: This depends on how you're actually accessing the file. I suggest checking the file in the Cloud Console ⇨ Storage Bucket and see what happens if you download it from there. Also check which content-type is listed there for the file (column "type"). You may need to set the content type while uploading the file. For a sample see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed storage client? as stated here.
https://packagist.org/packages/google/cloud-storage
use

```
composer require google/cloud-storage
```