# How does google storage file upload work for app engine using php?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am new to coding world.I want to upload a simple txt file to a bucket that is in my cloud storage. I didn't find any useful cloud documentations regarding it. 
here is the not working code:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
define("PROJECT_ID", 'projectID');
define("BUCKET_NAME", 'bucketname');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("API_Cloud_Storage");
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]);
$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$request = $service->objects->listObjects(BUCKET_NAME);
foreach ($request["items"] as $object)
  printf("%s\n", $object->getName());
  printf("%s\n", $object->get);
$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket(BUCKET_NAME); // Put your bucket name here.
$filePath="C:\users\useraccount\Desktop\address_file\textfile.txt";
$objectName="textfile.txt";
 $object = $bucket->upload(file_get_contents($filePath),
 ['name' => $objectName]);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue is in your code and there is an answer provided in a related question that you can refer to (it also has a link to another useful documentation) that can help you correct your code [1]. You can also rely on this sample code in GitHub [2].

In terms of the concept of uploading a local file to later provide public access to write to it. I think you may need to read a bit more about serving files uploaded with your app from the filesystem [3]. I also advise that you read through this entire documentation as it talks about serving files from a script or directly from GCS [4].

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/48559967

[2] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/php55/storage/app.php#L79

[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/#is_there_any_other_way_to_read_and_write_files

[4] 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/public_access#top_of_page

Comment: I also think problem is in uploading the content of file to storage and also reading the file through file_get_contents($filepath).Seems like file_get_contents is not working in the code because object gets created correctly. By the way [4] is useful as I am trying to implement now the logic of reading a file using html page that has a link to open the served file on storage using CloudStorageTools::serve("filename");

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately Google App Engine (GAE) provides a built-in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) stream wrapper that allows you to use many of the standard PHP filesystem functions to read and write files in an App Engine PHP app. I am also improving my coding skills and have found tips that worked for me in the GCP Documentation.

Taking from the code snippet you provided, you have to ensure you have done at least 2 things:

1. that you have properly created a storage bucket in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) [1].
   Make sure to replace "BUCKET_NAME" in your code with the name of the GCS bucket you created, and indicate the filepath to the text file you want to upload.
2. that you have configured your PHP app for writing files to your app [2], or to allow user uploads if you want other users to be able to upload files to your GCS bucket [3].

These are standard how-to guides (Tutorials are at the bottom of navigation bar) so make sure to view the examples provided on Github to take a look at the complete codes and adapt the style to yours.

Hope this helps!

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/#top_of_page

[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload

Comment: Thank you for replying. By the way, i have already learnt how to write files but the thing that i am stucked with since last few days is how to upload a file to storage. storage bucket has been created correctly as it works for writing files. I still need to figure out how reading and uploading works.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Following up on your question, let me take some time to reproduce the issue and then come back to you with a solution. In the meantime have a look at this documentation [1]. You can experiment with App Engine upload service to see if that works for you.

Comment: $upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload/handler', $options;

Comment: I am not getting what do I need to pass in the place of /upload/handler, a file which I want  to upload? Because I have tried to use this method also but it is not working. By the way thank you very much for your sincere help :)

Comment: Glad to help! Assuming that you are using the code provided in GitHub, you do not need to pass anything in place of '/upload/handler' because that refers to the method being called in PHP to handle user uploads.

Are you trying to write a code to upload a local file during deployment or handle external user uploads to your GCS bucket?

Comment: I am trying to upload a local file which I will need to read and write also for the next steps of implementation.

Comment: Please see the new [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50768149/9738014) I provided.

Comment: it is working now. Thank you for your useful file serving link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795642/file-get-contents-not-working-for-cloud-storage

Comment: createUploadUrl is not available on PHP7, can't let work upload of larger file without it :/ Some suggestion?