# file_get_contents not working for cloud storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

```
<?php
include'vendor\autoload.php';
define("PROJECT_ID", 'projectname');
define("BUCKET_NAME", 'bucketname');
$content=file_get_contents('C:\Users\Useraccount\PhpstormProjects\Projectname\filename.txt);
echo($content);
?>
```

This is the code that is working well on localhost but I am not able to get file contents on cloud storage. It simply shows me an empty page. Which are the possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: I am trying to upload a file to cloud storage. I am able to create object correctly but its content it missing. I realised it is due to file_get_contents not working.

Comment: Well your cloud storage probably doesn’t have a `C:\Users\Useraccount\PhpstormProjects\Projectname\filename.txt` …

Comment: Yeah,I have figured it out with the first answer to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the url where the storage located online, example `https://host.com/storage/mystorage/file.txt` and store this on variable on php.

```
<?php
    $target_url = 'https://host.com/storage/mystorage/file.txt';

    echo file_get_contents($target_url);
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much. It is working well now. I was confused in between local path and the path to file i serve on storage. Now it is working well for upload as well.